# How to modify a function behaviour without template method?

Tags: c++

I have a function (actually from ATL, it is `ATL::CSoapMSXMLInetClient::SendRequest(LPCTSTR)`)  whose behaviour should *slightly* be modified. That is, I just have to add one function call somewhere in the middle of the function.

Taking into consideration that this is not a template method, what is the best practice of changing its behaviour? Do I have to re-write the whole function?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Deriving from the class `ATL::CSoapMSXMLInetClient` and copy-pasting whole function code with a slight modification in subclass function definition does not work because most of the members used in `ATL::CSoapMSXMLInetClient::SendRequest` are "private" and accessing them in subclass is a compile time error.

Rather than best practice I am looking for a way to do it now, if there is any. :(

Comment: Why not template method?  Put a call to a protected virtual method at the right place.  Implement the protected method in base class as an empty method, then override in subclass.

Comment: i cannot change base class since it is ATL class

Answer (score 2):

Yes you will. If it's in the middle of the function there is no way of getting around it.

Comment: but i really don't want to :P anyway, it seems that i will have to :/ thanks for answer

Comment: and what if almost all base class members used in SendRequest are private... i cannot simply copy-paste the code to derived class...

Answer (score 1):

There are some refactoring methods you can use. But I cannot think of any pretty ones, and all depend heavily on the code within the class, although for you case it might be tough to find any that works.

Like if you have a line:

```
do_frobnicate();
dingbat->pling();
```

And you need to call somefunc() after the dingbat plings. You can, if the dingbat is an interface that you provide, make a new dingbat that also do somefunc() when it plings. Given that the only place this dingbat plings is in this function.

Also, if do_frobnicate() is a free function and you want to add the somefunc() after this, you could create a function within the class, or within its namespace that is called the same. That way you make your own do_frobnicate() that also does somefunc().

Comment: Well, i checked the code but I do not have such function which I can modify. My case is rather like:

func(x);
func(y);

and i want to add func(z); between them. But thanks for the answer anyway :)

Comment: Hopefully it might be helpful for others searching for similar answers.